# How to use a good VueX store design in a large SPA?

Tags: vue.js, redux, vuex, state-management

I do know VueJS kinda well, and I am familiar with the use of VueX. I am working on several VueJS projects, but I am struggling with the setup of my store.

A few questions I have:

- How do I split my modules? Per resource (projects, articles, et
  cetera), or per 'page / container' in my web app?
- What should a store contain (and persist)? UI state, or data, or both?
- How do I use a good naming for my modules, getters, actions and mutations?

> To be sure: I do know the syntax and use of Vue and VueX. My question
>   is focused on the structure / architecture of VueX and its store.

Hopefully you guys can help me with some terms or good video's / posts to work this out!

Thank you in advance, Bob

Comment: What did you ended up with? Split the modules per resource or per page? I've always split my modules per page, because it seems to make more sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many ways to organize your application store but here is how I do most of the time :

```
+ store
  - actions.js // global actions (like a for snackbar singleton, loader etc)
  - getters.js // global getters (like a for snackbar singleton, loader etc)
  - index.js // import all other indexes (in the subfolders)
  - mutations.js // global mutations (like a for snackbar singleton, loader etc)
  - state.js // global state (like a for snackbar singleton, loader etc)
  + common
    - actions.js // common actions (shared with all resources)
    - getters.js // common getters (shared with all resources)
    - mutations.js // common mutations (shared with all resources)
    - state.js // common state (shared with all resources)
  + subfolder1 // a resource (like an article, a user, ...)
    - index.js // imports common/* files or siblings overriding it, and exports it
    - actions.js // optional file overriding common/actions.js
    - getters.js // optional file overriding common/getters.js
    - mutations.js // optional file overriding common/mutations.js
    - state.js // optional file overriding common/state.js
  + subfolder2 // an other resource ...
  + ...
```

In the `common` folder, you have the code base for 'normal' resources, it helps to not duplicate it for each resource to deal with. If necessary, you can override it for a specific resource through a dedicated file which overrides the needed methods.

Here is an example of a file overriding the `fetchDB` method of the `common/actionos.js` file for a specific resource :

```
import { actions as baseActions } from "../common/actions"

const actions = Object.assign({}, baseActions) // we don't want to edit the base instance

// overrides the common method
actions.fetchDb = async function(context, args) {
  args.params.url = "myresource"
  await baseActions.fetchDb.call(this, context, args.params)
}

export default actions
```

The main advantage is that it reduces code duplication and keeps your resources separated, letting you the opportunity to adapt their behaviour if needed.

Do you think this organization could meet your needs ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think the separation of modules in a folder is very clear. As well your `baseActions`. But, some say that you should manage your modules based on 'feature', not on 'resource'. How do you face this?